# Redis Session provider broke when installing VS 2015

Tags: asp.net, redis, visual-studio-2015

After installing Visual Studio 2015 my app session doesn't work anymore. I'm using Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was I had an outdated version of the `Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider` package (0-0-3-Pre).

Be sure to update it to make it compatible with the new changes included in ASP.NET 4.6.

Open the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio, select your project and run:

```
Update-Package Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider
```